# How to query an index with a subcollection that has date ranges in RavenDB?

Tags: indexing, ravendb

I prepared the full test case here: https://gist.github.com/pkrakowiak/cc8addf5725193a01f2d

There are `Location` documents. Each location can have zero or more sponsors during some time periods (represented by the `IList<Sponsorship> Sponsors` property). I need to return only those locations that are sponsored on a particular day (say 15th of March in my example). So such location must have at least one `Sponsorship` instance that matches the following query: `.Where(x => x.Sponsors.Any(s => s.From <= today && s.To >= today))`

I prepared two tests, one is not using an index explicitly: `CanGetCurrentlySponsoredLocations`, and one which uses a static index that I created: `CanGetCurrentlySponsoredLocationsUsingStaticIndex`. The first one will pass, the second one will fail. The question is - how do I make the second test pass? What sort of modifications do I need to apply to my `Locations_ByCoordinates` index?

In case you are wondering where the index name came from or what the reviews are - just ignore them. :) They are leftovers from other things that I was testing.

**Update**

I took this question first to the official RavenDB Google group: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/ravendb/ySUPXqkpTA8 Sadly, it did not bring me a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest index that will pass your unit test is:

```
private class Locations_ByCoordinates : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Location>
{
    public Locations_ByCoordinates()
    {
        Map = locations => from l in locations
                           from s in l.Sponsors
                           select new
                           {
                               Sponsors_From = s.From,
                               Sponsors_To = s.To
                           };
    }
}
```

You might want to pick a better name, since the coordinates aren't indexed.

I'm not sure what your other test `CanSortOnSponsorshipStatus` is all about though.

**UPDATE**

To include locations that have no sponsors, use the `DefaultIfEmpty` linq extension method.  This will make sure that all locations have at least one index entry.

```
private class Locations_ByCoordinates : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Location>
{
    public Locations_ByCoordinates()
    {
        Map = locations => from l in locations
                           from s in l.Sponsors
                                      .DefaultIfEmpty(new Sponsorship
                                      {
                                        From = DateTime.MinValue,
                                        To = DateTime.MaxValue
                                      })
                           select new
                           {
                               Sponsors_From = s.From,
                               Sponsors_To = s.To
                           };
    }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't help - a Sponsorship is a pair of dates - From and To. The above will mix all dates and the query won't work as expected. See my comment here: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/ravendb/ySUPXqkpTA8/xTEPv_qGpKEJ

Coordinates are indexed in my real index. :) I just don't want to add extra stuff here.

Comment: Actually - no, they are not mixed.  Each pair is in a separate index entry.  I ran your test without the 3/11-3/15 range and it returned zero results as expected.  If you can prove otherwise, please update your unit test with this index and show me where it fails.

Comment: Also, you might consider using inclusive/exclusive ranges `s.From <= today && s.To > today`  - otherwise you might have overlaps.

Comment: I'm sorry, Matt. I did not pay attention and did not notice that you have a "join" in there. I tried similar code before but it was like `select new { Sponsors_From = l.Sponsors.Select(s => s.From), Sponsors_To = l.Sponsors.Select(s => s.To) }` which mixed the dates and caused the issue I linked to above. I immediately thought you gave me the same suggestion - my bad!

Comment: Not really a "join",  closer to a "select many". but I know what you are saying.  It's basically creating multiple index entries for the same document.  But you have control over the entire entry instead of just the parts.  Also, the underscore syntax is just to match the defaults from the query.  If you want to create a different return type, you can - you just have to use that in your query instead.

Comment: Thank you. I noticed that it puts in the index only the locations that have any sponsors. Is there a way to index all? I was hoping to be able to query for locations using Sponsors_From and Sponsors_To but also get locations that don't have any sponsors. The above query seems to work like an INNER JOIN equivalent of SQL, whereas I would like to do a LEFT OUTER JOIN (get all locations, some of them will have sponsors).